# Is it possible to change the key binding for completion in bash shell?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

For `bash`, I would to modify the tab key for completion to the escape key.
I know that key bindings are defined in `/etc/inputrc`.

But I don't know if something like this could work:

```
`"\e" : complete`
```

I want to do that because my users were from Solaris where the escape key does the auto-completion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the key binding or add key bindings to the `complete` function. This function is typically bound by default to <kbd>Tab</kbd> (which is the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) and <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by another <kbd>Esc</kbd>. However, it is not possible to bind the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key by itself to any Readline function. This is because the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is special and serves a couple of specific purposes in Readline.

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is used as a prefix for other key sequences, so entering an <kbd>Esc</kbd> by itself is only setting up the initial part of a full key sequence recognized by Readline. To see the list of all <kbd>Esc</kbd>-prefixed sequences recognized in bash, for example:

```
bind -p | grep '"\\e'
```

Because of the way Unix terminals are handled, an <kbd>Esc</kbd>-prefixed key sequence is usually the same as an <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key combination. So <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>u</kbd> is exactly the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is also used to exit out of Readline's interactive history search mode.

Comment: So you say it is not possible to use Esc for the completion instead of Tab in a bash shell ? And it is the only key that i can't bind to the completion function ?

Comment: It is not possible to bind `Esc` by itself, correct. But it is not the only key. For example, you could not bind the `Ctrl` key by itself to anything, `Ctrl` is only useful in combination with other keys.

Answer (score 1):

Double pressing escape has the same effect as single pressing tab. In this way, escape is already configured for completion.